# PHP while loop - exclude most recent row?

Tags: php

I have a PHP while loop that loads user comments - I need to exclude the most recent row in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.trackid, c.comment, c.time, c.userid, u.id, u.username FROM 
comments c
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = c.userid
WHERE trackid='$trackid'
ORDER BY c.time DESC";



$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<div class=\"commentDivs\">" . $row['time'] ."<br><br> " . $row['username'] . "<div class=\"userPostedComments\">" . $row['comment'] . "</div></div>";
}
```

How do I exclude the most recent row from the loop?

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way you will have to run 2 queries first to find the id of the latest comment ....

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$latest_id = $row['id'];
```

This will give you the latest id and then you can run the next query like this

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id != '$latest_id' ORDER BY id DESC");
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
 {    }
```

and let us know what you trying to do , might be that will make your code more clean

Comment: Might want to add `LIMIT 1` to that to stop MySQL from processing the whole set; Also create an index on `id`, if you haven't (by the looks of it it should be a primary key).

Comment: @Core Xii yup yup.... forget that

Answer (score 1):

If your query returns results sorted by most recent descending, you can do this on the query's side by specifying `OFFSET 1`.

Alternately, you can use [mysql_data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to move the row pointer however you need.

Comment: Or just ignore the first row you read.

Comment: @Vilx- indeed, it would work just fine if you did `mysql_fetch_assoc($result); for ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.trackid, c.comment, c.time, c.userid, u.id, u.username FROM 
comments c
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = c.userid
WHERE trackid='$trackid'
AND c.time != ( SELECT max(c.time) FROM comments WHERE u.id = c.userid )
ORDER BY c.time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide the database structure and the sql query so we can help , you can use `ORDER BY id` or store the time as `DATETIME` and `ORDER BY time` in the sql query

Answer (score 0):

You could use something as

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

then you can easily use $rows as an array, and can step in a for-loop until count($rows)-1

like

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows) - 1 ; $i++)
{
    print '<div class="commentDivs">' . $rows[$i]['time'] .'<br><br> ' . $rows[$i]['username'] . '<div class="userPostedComments">' . $rows[$i]['comment'] . '</div></div>';
}
```

EDIT: or you can jump over the specific line, if you hav not ordert them by the time...

or if you have it ordert DESC by the time yust modify my loop-header to

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($rows) ; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, using your current query:

```
for($i=1; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    mysql_data_seek($result, $i);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<div class=\"commentDivs\">" . $row['time'] ."<br><br> " . $row['username'] . "<div class=\"userPostedComments\">" . $row['comment'] . "</div></div>";
}
```